# No pid file generate when reinstall spring boot executable jar

Tags: spring-boot

I pack a executable jar and install it as init.d service normally. But when I reinstall it, the pid file and log file not generate. so it will failed when exec service appname start

How can I reinstall it?

the command below:

sudo ln -s /opt/bss-message/app.jar /etc/init.d/app1

when i link another script like:

sudo ln -s /opt/bss-message/app.jar /etc/init.d/app2

app2 has not pid file and log file.

Comment: what do you mean by "removing the old script and reinstalling it"?

Comment: please ignore it, i edit the question

Comment: reinstall it = copy a new version of the application (executable jar)?

Comment: yes, i install it using another app name

Comment: where is it written in your original description that you changed the name? Please edit your description and explain exactly what you're doing (commands, etc).

Comment: hi, i add my execution command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94178/discussion-between-stephane-nicoll-and-grapebaba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
$ sudo ln -s `pwd`/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/app1
$ sudo /etc/init.d/app1 start
Started [9732]
$ sudo ln -s `pwd`/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/app2
$ sudo /etc/init.d/app2 start
Started [9790]
$ ls /var/log/app*.log
/var/log/app1.log  /var/log/app2.log  /var/log/apport.log
$ ls /var/run/app1/
app1.pid
$ ls /var/run/app2/
app2.pid
```

Comment: OK, maybe my system issue.